# Haskell: Trying to make tapyclasses ala Rust dyn Trait for a FSM

Tags: haskell

I am a Haskell beginner, And I am trying to make a Finite State machine in Haskell like the one that Rob Pike show in his conference about Lexing and Go. Trough Rust-like dyn Traits.

Like this one.

```rust
pub struct Something {
    something: bool,
}

pub trait Saladable {
    fn next(&self, state: Something) -> (Box<dyn Saladable>, Something);
}

struct A;
struct B;

impl Saladable for A {
    fn next(&self, state: Something) -> (Box<dyn Saladable>, Something) {
        match state.something {
            true => (Box::new(A {}), Something { something: false }),
            false => (Box::new(B {}), Something { something: false }),
        }
    }
}

impl Saladable for B {
    fn next(&self, _state: Something) -> (Box<dyn Saladable>, Something) {
        (Box::new(A {}), Something { something: true })
    }
}
```

But when trying to convert it to Haskell

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
module Main where

main = undefined

data Something = Something Bool

class Saladable m where
  next :: Saladable f => Something -> (Something, f)

data A = A
data B = B

instance Saladable A where
  next (Something True) = (Something False, A)
  next (Something False) = (Something False, B)

instance Saladable B where
  next _ = (Something True, A)
```

I get this error

```
Test.hs:15:45: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘f’ with actual type ‘A’
      ‘f’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          next :: forall f. Saladable f => Something -> (Something, f)
        at Test.hs:15:3-6
    • In the expression: A
      In the expression: (Something False, A)
      In an equation for ‘next’:
          next (Something True) = (Something False, A)
    • Relevant bindings include
        next :: Something -> (Something, f) (bound at Test.hs:15:3)
   |
15 |   next (Something True) = (Something False, A)
   |                                             ^

Test.hs:19:29: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘f’ with actual type ‘A’
      ‘f’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          next :: forall f. Saladable f => Something -> (Something, f)
        at Test.hs:19:3-6
    • In the expression: A
      In the expression: (Something True, A)
      In an equation for ‘next’: next _ = (Something True, A)
    • Relevant bindings include
        next :: Something -> (Something, f) (bound at Test.hs:19:3)
   |
19 |   next _ = (Something True, A)
   |
```

Why I like is a idea of why this is happening, and how I can done to replicate that behavior of Rust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the most direct translation of that Rust code:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Something = Something Bool

data SomeSaladable = forall a. Saladable a => SomeSaladable a

class Saladable a where
  next :: (a, Something) -> (SomeSaladable, Something)

data A = A
data B = B

instance Saladable A where
  next (_, Something True) = (SomeSaladable A, Something False)
  next (_, Something False) = (SomeSaladable B, Something False)

instance Saladable B where
  next _ = (SomeSaladable A, Something True)
```

Here the `SomeSaladable` contains an existentially quantified type, see [this wikibook page for more info](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types).

But really, this is an antipattern in Haskell. Note that this `next` function can now no longer be chained. You have to unwrap the resulting `SomeSaladable`, so this is a pain to use.

A common solution can be found by asking: if you know that the only thing you can do with the resulting `Saladable` is to run the `next` function, then why don't you just store that? If you do that then you get something like this:

```hs
data Something = Something Bool

data Saladable = Saladable (Something -> (Saladable, Something))

next :: (Saladable, Something) -> (Saladable, Something)
next (Saladable f, x) = f x

a, b :: Saladable
a = Saladable (\(Something x) ->
  case x of
    False -> (a, Something False)
    True -> (b, Something False))

b = Saladable (\_ -> (a, Something True))
```

Comment: Great answer! This is an excellent example of the differences in paradigms. Both Rust and Haskell support the concept of existentials (Rust calls them trait objects, but it's the same idea). But in Rust, it's a normal feature that's used often, while in Haskell it's very fringe and generally frowned upon.

Comment: Probably worth a mention that encoding a FSM like that is called a Mealy machine. Libraries like [`machines`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines-0.7.2/docs/Data-Machine-Mealy.html#t:Mealy) provide some handy tools for working with them.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I've added a bit more explanation for why existential quantification is frowned upon in Haskell: it is annoying to use.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo What I want to consume input in a more flexible way, ergo what if I want to make so that some state transitions consume more input than anothers?, and what I want to arbitrary size consumption in transitions and also be able to peak future data?

Comment: @Delfin I think that is really a different question because I don't think your Rust code is capable of doing that either. If it is possible to do that, please update your question with an explanation of how you would do that in Rust. If not, feel free to ask about it in a new stack overflow question.